# Delete a record in Ember data not working

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a table (a component) and a delete button in each row. When the the delete button is clicked the specific row should be deleted.

Tried the following code:

MyComponent.js

```
  import Ember from 'ember';

   export default Ember.Component.extend({
   actions:{
    deleteCartRecord(cartDetails){
        debugger;
        this.sendAction('deleteRecord',cartDetails);
    }
 }

});
```

In MyComponent.hbs

```
{{#each model.orderParts as |newCart|}} 
  <div class="card-wrapper col-lg-12 col-md-12">
     <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2">
        <div class="order-id">{{newCart.partNumber}}</div>
       {{#if (gte newCart.promiseQty newCart.quantity)}}
    <div class="order-status delivered">{{env.APP.StockAvailable}}</div>
    {{else}} {{#if (gt newCart.promiseQty '0'(and (lt newCart.promiseQty newCart.quantity)))}}
    <div class="order-status intransit">{{env.APP.LowInStock}}</div>
    {{else}} {{#if (eq newCart.promiseQty '0')}}
    <div class="order-status outofstock">{{env.APP.OutofStock}}</div>
    {{/if}} {{/if}} {{/if}}
</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3">
    <div class="item-header">Delivery Date</div>
    <div class="item-data">{{newCart.deliveryDate}}</div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2">
    <div class="item-header">Required Qty.</div>
    <div class="item-data">
        {{increse-required-quantity incresedQuantity=newCart.quantity}}
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2">
    <div class="item-header">Unit Price</div>
    <div class="item-data">{{newCart.unitPrice}}</div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2">
    <div class="item-header">Total Price</div>
    <div class="item-data">{{newCart.partTotalPrice}}</div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 button-colum"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" {{action "deleteCartRecord" newCart}}>Delete</button>             </div>
  </div>
 {{/each}}
```

My Controller

```
   import Ember from 'ember';
   export default Ember.Controller.extend({
     actions:{
        deleteRecord(data){
          debugger; 
            let confirmation = confirm("are you sure to delete");
            if(confirmation)
            {
               debugger;
               data.deleteRecord();
               data.save();

            }
       }
  }
});
```

The template file in which component is called

```
    <hr>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
    <div class="checkout-summery-wrapper">
        <div class="total-label">Total</div>
        <div class="total">{{model.totalPrice}}</div>
        <!--<div class="tax-text">( Inclusive of all taxes )</div>-->
        <div class="place-order-button"><button type="button" class="btn siemens-btn">Place Order</button></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
    {{#if model.orderParts.isGeneric}}
    <div class="panel panel-default card-list-panel">
        <div class="panel-heading-cart col-lg-12 col-md-12">
            <div class="col-lg-11 col-md-11 heading">Generic Parts</div>
            <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1"><a href='#' class="delete-all">Delete All</a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            {{cart-record model = model}}
        </div>
    </div>
    {{/if}}
    {{#unless model.orderParts.isGeneric}}
    <div class="panel panel-default card-list-panel">
        <div class="panel-heading-cart col-lg-12 col-md-12">
            <div class="col-lg-11 col-md-11 heading">Hot Gas Path</div>
            <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1"><a href='#' class="delete-all">Delete All</a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            {{cart-record model = model deleteRecord=(action 'deleteRecord')}}
        </div>
    </div>
    {{/unless}}
</div>
```

MyRoute

```
 import Ember from 'ember';

  export default Ember.Route.extend({
     model: function()
     {
             return this.get('store').queryRecord('cart',{userId:1})
     }

  });
```

My Serializer

```
  import DS from 'ember-data';

  export default DS.JSONSerializer.extend(DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin, {
       primaryKey: 'totalPrice',

       attrs: {
        orderParts:
       {
           serialize: 'records',
           deserialize: 'records'
       }

    }

 });
```

I have the following issues:

1. In MyComponent.hbs, will newCart being passed as a parameter delete all the records or the specific record I want deleted?
2. Any ideas on why MyController is not invoked from the component?
3. Is this the correct way of deleting a record in ember?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> In MyComponent.hbs newCart is passed as a parameter will this delete all the record or the specific record i want?

It will delete the particular record alone. if you want to delete all the record then you can try `unloadAll('model-name')`

> MyController is not invoked from the component why is that?

You need to send action upcon calling component, `{{my-component deleteRecord=(action 'deleteRecords') }}` . Actually real problem is, you are calling `deleteRecord` but in controller you got `deleteRecords`.

> Is this the correct way of deleting a record in ember?

If you want to delete right away then you can use [`destroyRecord`](https://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html#method_destroyRecord) this will delete and save record immediately

Comment: Thnks for the answer, now the controller is invoked and the code is working fine but the record is not getting deleted i dont get an error too.

Comment: `{{action "deleteCartRecord" newCart}}` Just ensure `newCart` is record. Post  the code where are you including

Comment: `{{action "deleteCartRecord" newCart.partNumber}}` here you are sending `newCart.partNumber` i guess it should be `{{action "deleteCartRecord" newCart}}`

Comment: nope still not working i cant figure out what am i doing wrong :(

Comment: Just try console the output of newCart and check is it the record you want to delete . `{{log 'newCart ' newCart}}`

Comment: when i log newCart i get a class object. i cannot find the the data in this object

Comment: `{{log 'newCart id ' newCart.id}}` is it prinitng the id ? newCart should be the particular model record data. you might need to include the route model hook, to know how are you getting `orderParts `

Comment: orderParts is the attr property in the serializer. yes its printing the id

Comment: so where is the record you want to delete it from store ?.Only the record you got if from store can be deleted ?. Have a look at this https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.12.0/models/finding-records/ for getting records from store, only those records can call destroyRecord or deleteRecord.

Comment: am getting data from a api service and quering it using queryRecord so cant i delete that ???? is there another way

Comment: you can delete it,if you are getting it from queryRecord..please include route model hook. if its queryRecord then you will get single record, so `model.orderParts` this is the record right...then you can do `{{action "deleteCartRecord" model.orderParts}}` . if that is the case I dont know why you have to use `each` helper

Comment: what do you mean by "include route model hook" ??? can you give some more information? when i use model.orderParts it says destroyRecord is not a function.

Comment: Where are you including `my-component` ? please include corresponding template file and route file especially `model` method. which is where you will do queryRecord to get the `orderParts`.

Comment: i have updated the question with the route and the serializer code the template file is already there plzz help :)

Comment: so `model` is the record you want to delete. so `{{action "deleteCartRecord" model}}` this might work

Comment: am getting this error   "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:2000/api/cart/%24608.68. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 404"

Comment: So finally we got the DELETE request to server. you need to have endpoint to capture this request.. https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.12.0/models/creating-updating-and-deleting-records/#toc_deleting-records

Comment: Note: I havent done much work in ember-data. I am not familiar in ember-data. you can wait for some one shim in or you can join #ember-data channel in ember community slack https://ember-community-slackin.herokuapp.com/

Comment: thnks for the help really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, your example is full of bugs...

> 1. In MyComponent.hbs, will newCart being passed as a parameter delete all the records or the specific record I want deleted?

Nope.
Firstly, you need to understand that the result of `store.query` in your route returns a **DS.ManyArray**(an Array like object, which is **model** in your example) contains group of **DS.Model** instances (which should be **newCart** in your example, but you must change to `{{#each model as |newCart|}}` first). And only this **DS.Model** has method **.save()** and **.deleteRecord()**.
The action you set on the button is `{{action "deleteCartRecord" newCart.partNumber}}`, so you actually passing a **property** called partNumber to deleteRecord and running deleteRecord and save on this property. Unless this **partNumber** is a **DS.belongsTo** pointing to another **DS.Model**, or it cannot work at all.
But what you wanted is to delete newCart, right?

> 2. Any ideas on why MyController is not invoked from the component?

Your invoke is right. But since your component is full of bugs, it must be throwing exceptions somewhere else and the app cannot run already.

> 3. Is this the correct way of deleting a record in ember?

I think I answered enough in the first question.

Comment: if i remove the model.orderParts the data not getting filled in the component as orderParts is a serializer attr. my data is comming from a json api. i think i need a endpoint to capture this request. any suggessions?

Comment: First choice, make orderParts a **model**, and you got to have APIs for it of course, and in your cart model, set `orderParts: DS.hasMany('order-part')`, then you can use `orderPart.deleteRecord()`. Second choice, change your **deleteRecord** action, do something like `model.orderParts.removeObject(recordToDelete)`, and then save your model `model.save()`.

Comment: is it orderPart.deleteRecord or orderParts.deleteRecord ?? and where should i use this

Comment: @Azmy I use orderPart to represent one of the record of orderParts, use it in your deleteRecord, since a a lot of your code need to be changed to make it work.